# Visual Studio Context Menu Shortcut

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Does anyone know the keyboard shortcut in Visual Studio to open the context menu? i.e The equivalent of right clicking. Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> works in most Windows applications, but I don't have Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4):

You could also press the shortcut on your keyboard, if you have that key of course. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> works as well.